# C++ regex escaping punctional characters like "."

Tags: c++, regex, escaping

Matching a "." in a string with the `std::tr1::regex` class makes me use a weird workaround.

Why do I need to check for "\\\\." instead of "\\."?

```
regex(".") // Matches everything (but "\n") as expected.
regex("\\.") // Matches everything (but "\n").
regex("\\\\.") // Matches only ".".
```

Can someone explain me why? It's really bothering me since I had my code written using `boost::regex` classes, which didn't need this syntax.

**Edit:** Sorry, `regex("\\\\.")` seems to match nothing.

**Edit2:** Some code

```
void parser::lex(regex& token)
{
    // Skipping whitespaces
    {
        regex ws("\\s*");
        sregex_token_iterator wit(source.begin() + pos, source.end(), ws, regex_constants::match_default), wend;
        if(wit != wend)
            pos += (*wit).length();
    }

    sregex_token_iterator it(source.begin() + pos, source.end(), token, regex_constants::match_default), end;
    if (it != end)
        temp = *it;
    else
        temp = "";
}
```

Comment: What compiler and compiler options are you using?

Comment: I see you had the same issue in writing your question as I had with my answer. <.< that's why it initially said \ and \\, right?

Comment: Having tested this in Visual Studio 2012, I don't get the same issue. \\. seems to match "\.", as it should

Comment: @Agentlien Weird, maybe it's my code. I've posted the primary function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21017/discussion-between-agentlien-and-tim)

Comment: You know, the same version of C++ that included `std::regex` also included raw string literals.  You could say `R":(\.):"` and not have to escape so much -- just the stuff that the regex itself requires be escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the actual problem was due to the way `sregex_token_iterator` was used. Using `match_default` meant it was always finding the next match in the string, if any, even if there is a non-match in-between. That is,

```
string source = "AAA.BBB";
regex dot("\\.");
sregex_token_iterator wit(source.begin(), source.end(), dot, regex_constants::match_default);
```

would give a match at the dot, rather than reporting that there was no match.

The solution is to use `match_continuous` instead.

Comment: Actually it's not quite the problem.
The problem was that `it` doesn't match `end` since the string contains still characters. So a simple replacement of 
`if (it != end)` 
to 
`if (it != end && *it != "") `
fixed everything!

Answer (score 14):

This is because `\.` is interpreted as an escape sequence, which the language itself is trying to interpret as a single character. What you want is for your regex to contain the actual string "\.", which is written `\\.` because `\\` is the escape sequence for the backslash character (\).

Comment: See my example code, it just doesn't work the way you said. Besides it seems like "\\\\." doesn't work either.

Comment: For posterity: Tim had some formatting issues (SO interpreting \\ as \ inside posts) which led to the confusion behind my answer. However, having tried myself, \\. does work as expected in Visual Studio 2012, using std::regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the dot by its ASCII code:

```
regex("\\x2E")
```

Comment: @Tim can you show us the whole code you are using to match the string?

Comment: I did add the primary function. Thanks for helping out.